# Como conectar AppEngine Standard con Cloud SQL sin necesidad de usar 0.0.0.0/0

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, cloud

Tengo una aplicativo  montando en AppEngine y para poder permitir que el servicio de AppEngine pueda acceder a mi base de datos en cloud sql debo permitir todas las ip por medio de la regla 0.0.0.0/0, lo cual es una mala práctica. Tengo entendido que el app engine standard no maneja una ip fija, por lo que no puedo agregarla en la lista blanca, como se debe realizar esa configuración para no dejar por defecto la regla 0.0.0.0/0

Answer (score 0):

Claro
Puedes conectarte utilizadno la API de GCLOUD, por medio de una cuenta de servicio, o utilizando los accesos de API, para acceder a la instancia, aquí te dejo un link con el ejemplo, puedes checar para los dos tipos de Cloud SQL, MySQL y CloudSQL.

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-app-engine

Algo importante a tomar en cuenta, es que debes autenticar correctamente en tu aplicación y no tener las credenciales en en "hardcore", debido a que GAE mismo no te permitirá realizar un deploy con las credenciales en tu código.